# Smoothing and normalizing a singular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves

If we have a singular curve for example nodal curve then we can define its normalization.
I read somewhere we have also smoothing a singular curve
Does anyone know the definition or any references?

Comment: For curves, normalization is a resolution of singularities.

Comment: I know about normalization.I want to know what we mean by smoothing?

Comment: You should specify in your question more about what you know. It was unclear whether you knew that the normalization of a curve is smooth. A smoothing result is usually a statement about families of curves, not just a fixed curve, that tells you the codimension of the locus of singular fibers of the family.

Comment: Would you please introduce some references for such smoothing results?

Comment: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0074998.  Here’s one where a bit of the history is explained in the introduction.